# Difference between storing in app.locals vs global object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I saw some people use `app.locals` to store properties that is available across all views.

Also other people used `global.AnyNameVariable` to store anything even like requiring `config.js` files and etc

**ex:**

```
app.locals.objOne = {
      name:'John'
}

global.objTwo = {
      name:'Doe'
}
```

What is the difference between them? and what is the purpose? what is the right way to use both?

Comment: Have you read the docs on [app.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals)? Have you read about the [globals](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) in Node?

Comment: Yes i read both, but when it comes to globals i didn't understand much from the documentation, it says that object are globals per module but when i tested it it turned out i could access its properties in any file

Comment: The reason I asked was because the way you've worded the question most answers would presumably just regurgitate what the docs say - so what is the real question? Is it really why can you access `global.objTwo` across modules? I think the express docs do a good job of explaining the `app.locals` property

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) states,

> The app.locals object has properties that are local variables within the application.

This is application-level container provided by the framework that serves to store application settings, etc. There can be more than one Express application, while `global` is global.

`app.locals` is available as [`req.app.locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.app) within middlewares, this way it can be decoupled from specific `app` variable.